# Setting tsconfig baseURL in stencilJS project does not work

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, stenciljs

I set a baseUrl in tsconfig.json to be '.' in my stenciljs web project. Then when I run "npm start" to start the stenciljs server emulator, none of the components work (i.e. nothing shows on the screen).  I've done some research and suspect this may be in the stencil-router component set up in the stenciljs root component but I  do not know if this problem has a solution: i.e. can I use baseURL in .tsconfig and  also have my components load.  Any answers  will be appreciated.

tsConfig.json sample (... indicates parts I'm not showing)

```javascript
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: How did you set it? Can you show your actual `tsconfig.json`? (Also note the new file name differs from what you have, what version of typescript are you running?)

Comment: What is the specific goal of adding/modifying the value `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json`? What kind of stenciljs template did you start with for this project? Did you change the folder structure? Also shared your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @msanford: included snipped & corrected filename to tsconfig.json

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky: baseurl enables me to specify import paths that are relative to a root directory in my project.  A good explanation of the motivation can be found at: https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/